# Parse Livequeries don't handle events suddenly since yersterday

Tags: parse-platform, parse-live-query

I'm using Parse platform with livequeries.
It's deployed since 2 years and everything works fine until yesterday.
Everything is ok on server side but on client side (IOS app with ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX) I can see the events in Xcode console but it's not handled by the function.

Is anyone else facing issues suddenly since yesterday ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share some code that shows your problem?

Comment: Same for me.
Recently LiveQuery module has been added to Parse SDK.